# How to count the number of duplicate in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have tables like following
I'd like to count duplicate and assign them.

```
customer date       type
A       2020/8/1     a
A       2020/8/1     b
B       2019/5/1     a
B       2019/6/1     c
```

I'd like to `count` duplicate in `customer`and`date` the, assign the number of `duplicate` of them.

`["customer,"date"]`

```
customer date     type     duplicate
A       2020/8/1   a       2
A       2020/8/1   b       2
B       2019/5/1   a       1
B       2019/6/1   c       1
```

If someone has opinion to assign the number of duplicated rows.
Please let me know. thanks

Answer (score 1):

With `count() over` analytical function.`Date` is reserved word

```
SELECT c.*,
       COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY "customer","date") duplicate 
FROM   tablename c;
```

If you wanted to format date column

```
SELECT "customer",
        to_char("date",'DD-MON-YYYY HH:MI:SS AM') "date",
        "type",
       COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY "customer","date") duplicate 
FROM tablename ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below -

```
select a.customer,a.date,type,duplicate 
from tablename a
join 
(select customer,date, count(*) as duplicate from tablename group by customer, date) b 
on a.customer=b.customer and a.date=b.date
```