# SQL: How to count number of duplicate entries and add that number into same row

Tags: sql, database

I have a table with numerous duplicate records that I can identify by ID. I want to count number of entries inside of the table for each row (for each ID) and add that number inside of specific column (Num of Duplicates).
Example of table:
ID
AB1
AB2
AB1
AB3
AB2
AB1

[Example of outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62GKn.png)

I've tried both solutions described in a post here
[How to count the number of duplicate in sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63497768/how-to-count-the-number-of-duplicate-in-sql)

First one filled Num of Duplicates column with the same number of total count of entries inside of the table. i.e:
ID    Num of DUP
AB1   6
AB2   6
AB1   6
AB3   6
AB2   6
AB1   6

Solution 2 - no results at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `COUNT()` here as an analytic function:

```sql
SELECT ID, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) AS cnt
FROM yourTable;
```